# The cdf of a sum of two independent random variables with type I extreme-value distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, independence, exponential-sum

Consider two random variables $X,Z$. Assume that they are **independent** and that they both have **type I extreme-value distribution**, i.e. their cdf follows
$$
F(a)\equiv \exp(-\exp(-a))
$$
Is there any result giving a closed form for the cdf of $W\equiv X+Z$?